# How can I expand a:000 list in order to pass through all varargs parameters to another function?

Tags: vimscript, functions, list

I have a varargs function, which I want to refactor to include a separate 'argument handling function' first, so that that becomes separately callable. I've read `:help function-argument` but was unable to discover how to expand `a:000`, which comes as a list of strings, so that bar can also accept varargs in the same way?

```
fu! Foo(...) abort
  let s = Bar(a:000[???])
endfunction
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:h call()`:

```
func! Bar(...) abort
    return a:000
endfunc
func! Foo(...) abort
    echo call('Bar', a:000)
endfunc

call Foo('asdf', 'qwer') " --> ['asdf', 'qwer']
```